# ng-click does not work on my directive of a slider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-click

I use the structure provided by the yeoman with angular-generator.

The ng-click does not work in my directive, of a slider show, when I put the html directly in main.html (It only works when I put in the directive an templateurl, linked to the main.html , but this causes delay to load).

Html, that is inserted directly into main.html

```
<div images="images" class="slider" id="mauseOnOut">
    <div  class="slide" ng-repeat="image in images" ng-show="image.visible"> 
        <a ng-href="{{image.url}}"><img ng-src="{{image.src}}" width="444" height="250"/>
        <p class="texto">{{image.texto}}</p>
        </a>
    </div>

    <ul class="minimagem" ng-show="images.length"> 
      <li ng-repeat="image in images"><a ng-click="returner($index)"><img ng-src="{{image.src}}" width="70" height="56"/></a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="arrows">
        <a href="" ng-click="prev()" ><img  src="http://s5.postimg.org/orczpkx0z/left_arrow.png"/></a> <a href="" ng-click="next()"><img src="http://s5.postimg.org/qkfwdwi7n/right_arrow.png"/></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Main part of the `directive` (in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5t57n/75/) have it complete)

```
 myApp.directive('images', function ($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope:{
        images: '='
    },
    link: function (scope) {

        scope.currentIndex=0;


    scope.returner = function(index){
    scope.currentIndex = index;
};

        scope.next=function(){
            scope.currentIndex<scope.images.length-1?scope.currentIndex++:scope.currentIndex=0;
        };

        scope.prev=function(){
            scope.currentIndex>0?scope.currentIndex--:scope.currentIndex=scope.images.length-1;
        };

        scope.$watch('currentIndex',function(){
            scope.images. forEach(function(image){
                image.visible=false;
            });
            scope.images[scope.currentIndex].visible=true;
        });

    },

  };
});
```

Put an example in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5t57n/75/) ; when use angular 1.1, on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5t57n/75/), operate normally, with 1.2 or higher does not work. In my application I use the angular 1.3.10 .

How could make it work in my application? It could be to ' compile ' or in some other way , the important thing is the click staying active in the image thumbnails and arrows .

**Edited**: I came back with the best known directive , best to understand.

Comment: I've never seen a factory being defined like that. Another thing is that I'm not seeing the property TemplateUrl.

Comment: This is the ["directive definition object"](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) . I tried this new form of directive in an attempt to solve the problem of ng- click . In relation to another position: The html is inserted directly into main.html , therefore, do not need templateUrl.

Comment: For a directives link function to be bound to the template, the template needs to be the directives template.  Your `prev` and `next` functions are being executed in the context of the parent controller.

Comment: @BenFelda, How do I transfer all that is directive to the controller ? I tried a few times without success.

Comment: You can either take the functionality out of the directive, getting rid of the directive all together and just put it into the controller, or move the html into a template of the directive.  Just to get it working, I would just put it all in the controller first, then move it into a directive so you can see what breaks.

Comment: @BenFelda, Could you give me a practical example of how to do?